# How do I find location of executable file?

Tags: macos, terminal

I was not able to use Illuminated Cloud on Mac since it required to enter Salesforce DX executable path which I don't know.

When I installed SFDX by downloading and executing installer https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-osx.pkg, it never asked me for a folder to install, so I didn't understand where it was installed.

How do I find where SFDX executable is installed to paste it here?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) How did you install Salesforce DX?

Comment: by downloading installer https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli and then running it

Comment: I just notice it's you who typed the answer as well. Did that work for you?

Comment: yes, I copied the answer from this question https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272125/how-do-i-find-sfdx-cli-default-installation-folder-on-mac/272128#272128 and combined my previous approach and the simpler way suggested

Comment: so the actual link which points to installer is https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-osx.pkg

Comment: Please don't cross-post questions to several StackExchange sites at once. Post on one which is suitable and then, if you don't get answers within a few days, flag it for mod attention to have it migrated to another suitable site.

Comment: @nohillside do you mean I shouldn't cross-post question even if a question might relate to several domains? Like in this case, it relates to both Salesforce development tools and Mac usage, so I think it can be on both sites

Comment: Yes indeed, you shouldn't cross-post at all as it leads to several independent comment and answer streams, with a lot of redundancy and general loss of quality. *If* there are several suitable sites, *and* you don't get answers on the first, then have it migrated to another suitable one.

Answer (score 2):

From https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272125/how-do-i-find-sfdx-cli-default-installation-folder-on-mac:

The simplest way is the type a command

```
which sfdx
```

in Terminal.

```
/usr/local/bin/sfdx
```

Another (longer and more complicated) way (which I initially used) is to type command

```
find / -iname sfdx
```

in the Terminal and search in the results for the actual path

```
/usr/local/lib/sfdx/bin/sfdx
```